# Selecting specific table for each subscriber when using merge replication in SQL Server with multiple subscribers

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2017, merge-replication

I am using merge replication with SQL Server 2017.

I have one publisher, and two subscribers (all in all 3 database servers).

I need to replicate different tables to each subscriber.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, that is possible - you create 3 different publications - and in each publication you add only the respective tables you want for each server.

for example - only 2 tables for `server1`
[image]

The other tables will be in other publications, not this one.

Alternatively, within the merge replication you can set up *filters* and each subscriber would *see* only a specific partition as you define it.

This example below comes from this article:

[Merge SQL Server replication parameterized row filter issues](https://www.sqlshack.com/merge-sql-server-replication-parameterized-row-filter-issues/)

add tables to merge replication with parametrized row filters.

Follow the steps in the [referenced article](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-replication-merge-what-gets-replicated-and-what-doesnt/) to configure merge publication and adding tables to the publication

At Add filter step add below filter.

```
SELECT <published_columns> FROM [dbo].[UserDetails] WHERE [UserOrg] = HOST_NAME()
```

[image]

Once the publication setup is completed, generate the snapshot for merge replication. After generating the snapshot navigate to publication, right click and click on Properties -> Data Partitions

[image]

Click on Add and enter the partition value i.e. ORG1 and click ok. As of now I am adding only one partition ORG1. We can add more based on subscribers. For example, if I have a subscriber with partition ORG2 then we can add partition for ORG2 here and generate a partitioned snapshot which will be applied on specific subscriber.

[image]

Now click on generate the selected snapshot now and click OK.

[image]

Right click on publication in merge replication, launch SQL Server replication monitor and make sure the partitioned snapshot is also completed.

[image]

Now add subscription. Please follow steps in the following article to add subscriber: Merge Replication – [What gets replicated and what doesn’t](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-replication-merge-what-gets-replicated-and-what-doesnt/)

While adding the subscriber specify the HOST_NAME() value of the subscriber, so that the rows with UserOrg value ORG1 only will be replicated to the subscriber.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I did not explained my self enough. The three servers have a common set of tables that they need to replicate between all of servers. Beside these tables, each of the two subscribers need to synchronize a unique set of tables with the publisher.
Do I have to create 2 different publications (which means to public the common table set twice), or is there a way to specify the tables set for each subscribers?

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect this. you might be able to do it with one publication - check if you can figure out how to manage the filters. I used to work for a political party in the UK - we had merge replication with over 250 subscribers - each will see only their share in the main database.

Comment: At first look, I thought that filtering will not do the job, since I need to filter which tables gets synchonized, not rows, But I think this can be used also in my case, if I make the row filterring return all rows for one subscriber, and no rows for the other one. Thanks!